# Best practice to run a prebuild step with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, prebuild

Suppose you have a repository with a folder (named dataset) with several .csv files and a python script (named csvcut.py) that takes all the .csv in dataset and generates corresponding .h files.

Those .h files are included in some .cpp files to build an executable (`add_executable(testlib...`) used for testing.

Suppose you use `add_custom_target(test_pattern...` to make a target (named test_pattern) that runs csvcut.py, and `add_dependencies(testlib test_pattern)` to run the script before building testlib.

This works, but it would be better if:

- the script was run only when the files in dataset folder or the script itself changes (not when .cpp changes);
- the .h files was generated in a subfolder of the build folder (i.e. build/tests/dataset/), and included in the .cpp files like so `#include <tests/dataset/generated.h>`.

Do you have any suggestions for making these improvements / optimizations?

Thanks, Alberto

Comment: The first task seems hard, but the second one seems easy. You can pass `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` to the gererator script, so that it can put the generated files to the build folder. Then add `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` as include directory to the related target (executable or library) with `target_include_directories`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requires multiple steps, but can all be handled with standard CMake.  First, we'll use `add_custom_command` to actually generate the files.  I'm also adding a custom target, but only since I couldn't figure out how to make an `INTERFACE` library work without it.

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include/foo.h"
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gen.py"
    DEPENDS
        gen.py
        foo.h.in
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include"
)
add_custom_target(gen_files
    DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include/foo.h"
)
```

For my case, `gen.py` just spits out a basic header file, but it shouldn't matter.  List whatever files you need as output, and your csv file should be under `DEPENDS` (for me, `foo.h.in` tries to simulate this).

Since you only mentioned generating header files, I created an `INTERFACE` library that depends on the `gen_files` target.  I also added the appropriate include directory.

```
add_library(foo INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(foo
    INTERFACE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include"
)
add_dependencies(foo
    gen_files
)
```

If building a `STATIC`/`SHARED` library, I was able to add the generated files directly as sources and dependencies worked, but the `INTERFACE` library required the extra target (even when I tried listing the files under `add_dependencies`).  Since you already have a custom target, I assume this won't be a huge issue.

Lastly, I have an executable that links against `foo`.

```
add_executable(main
    main.c
)
target_link_libraries(main
    PRIVATE
        foo
)
```

Demo:

```
$ make clean 
$ ls
CMakeCache.txt  CMakeFiles  cmake_install.cmake  include  Makefile
$ make
[ 33%] Generating include/foo.h
[ 33%] Built target gen_files
[ 66%] Building C object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable main
[100%] Built target main
$ make clean
$ make main
[ 33%] Generating include/foo.h
[ 33%] Built target gen_files
[ 66%] Building C object CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable main
[100%] Built target main
$ make
[ 33%] Built target gen_files
[100%] Built target main
$ touch ../foo.h.in 
$ make
[ 33%] Generating include/foo.h
[ 33%] Built target gen_files
[100%] Built target main
$ touch ../gen.py 
$ make
[ 33%] Generating include/foo.h
[ 33%] Built target gen_files
[100%] Built target main
$ ls include/
foo.h
```

If either the input (`foo.h.in`) or generation script (`gen.py`) change, the targets are rebuilt.

Comment: Great! Your example was very helpful in solving my problem. For the first time I used the combination of add_custom_command and add_custom_target which could be useful to me in many other scenarios. Thank you!